# Catching unhandled exceptions in Rhino

Tags: javascript, exception, rhino

I'm using Rhino Script Engine and was wondering if it's possible (and how) to register a global handler that could be invoked whenever an unhandled exception is triggered.

I know that I cannot use browser objects like `window` to register a handler with something like:

```
window.addEventListener("error", function (e) {
  alert("Error occurred: " + e.error.message);
  return false;
})
```

Is there an alternative?

Comment: Can you describe more thoroughly how Rhino is being invoked? The approach to use (and how good it is) would depend on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending *exactly* what you want -- and exactly what you have -- here's one approach:

```js
var setUncaughtExceptionHandler = function(f) {
 Packages.org.mozilla.javascript.Context.getCurrentContext().setErrorReporter(
  new JavaAdapter(
   Packages.org.mozilla.javascript.ErrorReporter,
   new function() {
    var handle = function(type) {
     return function(message,sourceName,line,lineSource,lineOffset) {
      f({
       type: type,
       message: String(message),
       sourceName: String(sourceName),
       line: line,
       lineSource: String(lineSource),
       lineOffset: lineOffset
      });
     };
    };

    ["warning","error","runtimeError"].forEach(function(name) {
     this[name] = handle(name);
    },this);
   }
  )
 );
};

setUncaughtExceptionHandler(function(error) {
 Packages.java.lang.System.err.println("Caught exception: " + JSON.stringify(error,void(0),"    "));
});

var x = true;
var y = null;
var z = y.foo;
```

The output for this is:

```
Caught exception: {
    "type": "error",
    "message": "uncaught JavaScript runtime exception: TypeError: Cannot read property \"foo\" from null",
    "sourceName": "null",
    "line": 0,
    "lineSource": "null",
    "lineOffset": 0
}
```